# Applying modulus to determinant

Tags: matrices, modular-arithmetic

I'm have trouble understanding how to get the determinant of a matrix and apply a modulus to it.

I have have $((6)(16) - (15)(5))^{-1} \mod29$

I have no idea how to break this down.

Comment: mod 26 is a bit weird. Anyway, 6x16-15x5=21. Can you find an integer $n$ such that when $21n$ is divided by 26, the remainder is 1? If so, that $n$ is the answer.

Comment: Yes sorry made a mistake, supposed to be mod 29.

Comment: The same approach applies. Find an $n$ such that the remainder of $21n$ divided by 29 is 1. That way, $21n$ is equal to 1 in modular arithmetic and hence $n$ is the inverse/reciprocal of 21, modulo 29.

Comment: I figured it out, thanks for the help. I basically just use Euler algorithm? Getting the gcd.

Comment: Hmm, how? What is your answer anyway?

Comment: As you have figured it out, please write it up and post it as an answer.